What is this short story about aliens and Christmas carols?
I read this SF short story in English at least 30 years ago. I suppose it was in a collection as I only very seldom read magazines.
A few aliens have come to Earth, but they never communicate. They come out of their spaceship in the morning, follow the guides human send to them, and go back in their spaceship in the evening.
Except for going along, they do not show any reaction to any attempts to communicate.
Then one day, in Yuletide season, in a place (possibly a commercial mall) where a Christmas carol can be heard in the background they suddenly sit down. By inspecting a video of this exact instant, one can hear the verb "to sit" in some form or other. A bit later they all get up.
From then on, one tries to make them hear songs (mostly, but not only, Christmas carols) where the verb "to sit" appears, mostly with no result. Occasionally, they do sit down again, and IIRC, not always on a Christmas carol. Nobody can understand why they sit down when they do and why not in the other attempts.
I don't remember exactly what the solution was, but it was found at the end, and communication started.

This is the novella All Seated on the Ground by
Connie Willis, which you can read online here.

The aliens have landed! The aliens have landed! But instead of shooting death rays, taking over the planet and carrying off Earthwomen, they've just been standing there for months on end, glaring like a disapproving relative. And now it's nearly Christmas, and the commission assigned to establish communications is at their wits' end. They've resorted to taking the aliens to Broncos games, lighting displays, and shopping malls, in the hope they'll respond to something!
And they do, but in a way nobody ever expected, and Meg, the commission, and an overworked choir director find themselves suddenly caught up in an intergalactic mess involving Christmas carols, scented candles, seventh-grade girls, Alvin and the Chipmunks, Meg's Aunt Judith, Victoria's Secret, and Handel's Messiah.

This review mentions the sudden and unexpected sitting.

One day, they take the aliens to a mall and the Altairi suddenly sit down in unison. Dr. Morthman, the chair of the commission is very excited, yelling orders everywhere and demanding to know what caused this reaction. Despite wanting answers, he never pauses to listen to anyone else, and ignores Meg when she tries to tell him anything. So Meg goes off on her own to figure it out with the help of a choir director named Calvin Ledbetter.


When will I learn!?  Answer, then quotes!

Btw, this is definitely the right answer, not a "could this be."

https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v31n12_2007-12/page/n13/mode/1up

That was fast !

@DavidW - There's very little mileage in being second

I always start my Story ID answers with "Could this be" as it makes it easier to search for them, in order to prod OP for an acceptance. It's what made this monstrosity possible...

@DavidW I read it last night and quite enjoyed it. I was particularly amused that the two leads were named Meg and Calvin. That's got to be a Wrinkle in Time reference.
